# How can I stablize an analog to digital reading?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, analog, potentiometer, stability

I've built a clock out of a PIC16F877, some LEDs and other stuff...

To set the time in 5 minute intervals, I'm using a 22K ohm potentiometer connected between GND and +5V with the contact connected to analog input RA0 on my MCU.

It works, but it badly fluctuates between values. It's a 10bit ADC, and I'm looking at the most significant 8bits, and if I get my pot roughly in the center, I get an average reading of 128, but it flickers between 127, 128 and 129... even if I leave it alone and don't touch it.

How can I stablise the reading? I could probably write firmware to take an average reading, which may help a bit, but before I mess around with that wondered if there is something I could add (caps, resistors, etc) to my circuit to make it more stable? In this part of the circuit, I just have the pot connected to the MCU, nothing else.

Comment: Averaging a number of ADC readings should improve things, but to really fix the problem, you should use the processor's clock, or a counter/timer based on that clock (assuming it is crystal controlled).

Comment: Do you have both decoupling and supply caps on the board?

Comment: The analog pots won't give a stable resistance value sometimes, try with digital pots.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, I have decoupling and supply capacitors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have noise in your system, plain and simple.  How you handle it is the same ways that you handle any other noise: remove the source of the noise, or filter out the noise.  Some things to consider are:

- Long cables can cause noise.  Shorten them, or use shielded cables
- Use differential measurements, if possible.
- Make sure that you use good power distribution, routing, and filtering.
- Make sure that your PCB is designed to reduce noise on the important signals.
- Placing a cap on your ADC input pin, between the pin and GND, can help reduce noise from a pot.  This C, plus the R that is your pot, form an RC low pass filter.  The larger the cap, the better the filtering (but the slower the system will respond to changes of the input).  I would start with a 0.1 uF cap, and go up from there.
- Use a lower-value POT.  10K, 5K, or even 1K ohm.  This effectively decreases the output impedance of your sensor (the pot) and reduces the chances of picking up noise.  Make sure you do not exceed the power limits on the pot.
- Filter the signal in software.  It could be as simple as having a moving average, or you could do a more complex form of filter.  The longer time that you average the signal, the better effective resolution you will get, with the obvious down-sides.
- Make sure that you are operating the ADC in the MCU correctly.

Comment: First thing I tried: I put a 0.0uF cap between GND and the middle pin of the pot, and it has completely resolved the problem! The ADC value it now perfectly stable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BG100 You put how large a capacitor there?

Comment: Oops, typo... I mean 0.01uF

Answer (score 3):

From memory, the ADC input on this PIC requires the "signal" to be a "low" output impedance (22kohm pot would be too high) and this means having a capacitor across the input pin. The ADC type on these devices are "successive approximation" and they will cause noise on the input pin - this will be seen as a measurement error.

In the past I have decoupled slow moving inputs with a 100nF across input to ground and fed the input with a series resistor of a couple of kohm. For higher speed signals you would use a decent op-amp buffer to achieve a low output-impedance drive to the ADC input.

You may also have problems with your ADC reference voltage inputs - these may be internally selected to be connected to you Vcc and ground however, if they are connected to proper voltage references and your 22k pot is connected across the Vcc to ground, changes in Vcc will get through. Make sure you have a ratiometric measurement or expect to have these sort of discrepencies.

Comment: Thanks. I added a cap between GND and the ADC port and if fixed my problem completely, even with a 22K. I have also ordered some 10K pots, but their still on their way here from Hong Kong... 22K is all I had lying around.